# Unable to make folders to zip files using java?

Tags: java, zip, directory, unzip

Here i have folder(Books)structure inside of Books folder i have folders called physics,chemistry,science,english.I'm passing Books folder as zipDeleteFile but inside all folder has to convert in the same folder(Books)as physics.zip,chemistry.zip,science.zip,english.zip.But this code is not working.

'

```
public void foldertToZip(File zipDeleteFile) {
    //System.out.println(zipDeleteFile);
    File directoryToZip = zipDeleteFile;
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    //System.out.println("---Getting references to all files in: " + directoryToZip.getCanonicalPath());
    getAllFiles(directoryToZip, fileList);
    //System.out.println("---Creating zip file");
    writeZipFile(directoryToZip, fileList);
    //System.out.println("---Done");
}

public static void getAllFiles(File dir, List<File> fileList) {
    try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            fileList.add(file);
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                getAllFiles(file, fileList);
            } else {
                System.out.println("     file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void writeZipFile(File directoryToZip, List<File> fileList) {
    try {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directoryToZip.getName() + ".zip")) {
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (File file : fileList) {
                if (!file.isDirectory()) { // we only zip files, not directories
                    addToZip(directoryToZip, file, zos);
                }
            }

            zos.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public static void addToZip(File directoryToZip, File file, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        String zipFilePath = file.getCanonicalPath().substring(directoryToZip.getCanonicalPath().length() + 1,
                file.getCanonicalPath().length());
        System.out.println("Writing '" + zipFilePath + "' to zip file");
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(zipFilePath);
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
}`'
```

Initially i'm passing zipDeleteFile as C:\Books inside Books i have all physics,english,science folder those folders has to convert into zip files in the same root folder(Books).

Comment: Please don't silently swallow Exceptions.

Comment: @MadProgrammer,its not conveting to zip files.

Comment: Works fine for me.  I can view the contents of the file in Windows Explorer, which is always a good sign

Comment: @MadProgrammer,not showing as zip files after conversion.I'm doing any mistake here.

Comment: What do you mean by *"not showing as zip files"*?  You code creates a zip and I can read it's contents through Windows just fine

Comment: @MadProgrammer,after conversion to zip files ,inside Books folder,Science.zip,english.zip file has to show.But it is not showing here,instead showing the Science ,english as folders only.

Comment: Ahh, so you want to create the sub folders as zip files and then add them to the master zip?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54957/discussion-between-thaz-ahammad-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, you want to zip each of the directories in the `Books` folder into their own zip file.  There is a couple of ways you could do this, but the eaiest might be to change the way you are calling `foldertToZip`

So, instead of (something like)...

```
foldertToZip(new File("C:\\Books"));
```

You could do something like...

```
for (File file : new File("C:\\Books").listFiles()) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        foldertToZip(file);
    }
}
```

This will result in each directory within `Books` been added to it's own zip file, which will reside within `Books`

One other change you might need to make is...

```
public static void writeZipFile(File directoryToZip, List<File> fileList) {
    try {
        //try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directoryToZip.getName() + ".zip")) {
        File path = directoryToZip.getParentFile();
        File zipFile = new File(path, directoryToZip.getName() + ".zip");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile)) {
```

This will create the zip file within the parent directory of the directory to be zipped (ie, the `Books` directory)

Comment: here i'm passing this zipDeleteFile as file then it cant show .listFiles(),right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  The example above stops the contents of ``Books`` from been generated into a zip file and instead, zips the individual sub directories instead

Comment: Made a slight update to ensure the zip files are created within the `Books` directory...

Comment: How can i do that,any idea please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54960/discussion-between-thaz-ahammad-and-madprogrammer).